# Alternative to Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client in ASP.NET Core 2.0 class library

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

Recently updated an ASP.NET Core 1.x (.NET Framework) class library to an ASP.NET Core 2.0 (.NET Core) class library and ran into one problem.

The class library relies on Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client v5.2.3

It seems like this client only works with .NET Framework. Is the best current solution for the time being to get Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client v5.2.4 alpha which works with .NET Core 2.0?

Comment: Have you tried [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim/)?

Comment: @IvanMilosavljevic No I did not try this. I am wondering if all of the functions will still be there.

Comment: @IvanMilosavljevic This worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim/)?

*** Update 11/01/2018 ***

Compat shim now depends on latest Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client package (5.2.4-preview1). More about this change [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/286)